# SpyderKernelApp WARNING No such comm in windows 10 on spyder3 ide

Tags: performance, anaconda, spyder, python-3.8

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self,a=40):
        self.speed = a
    def get_speed(self):
        return self.speed
    def set_speed(self, a):
        self.speed = a
        return
    speed = property(get_speed,set_speed)
c1 = Person()
print(c1.speed)
```

i am getting this error on the above code"[SpyderKernelApp] WARNING | No such comm: 75356698486711eba96dccb0da3ca80e"